# Любить и нравиться

Tags: семантика, выбор-слов

Ищу хорошее подробное разъяснение употребления слов "любить" и "нравиться".

Сама пришла к следующим выводам:

- очевидно, что "любить" - это более сильная степень привлекательности для человека какого-либо объекта, чем "нравиться";
- "любить"  - говорит о явлении вообще, а "нравиться" - об отношении к конкретным его представителям: *"Я люблю этого писателя, но его новая книга мне не нравится"*;
- мы не говорим "любить" об одежде, только "нравится":  *"Мне нравится это платье. Мне очень нравятся эти джинсы"*. В то же время можно сказать *"Я люблю это платье"* - но это не будет означать "очень нравится". Значение "люблю платье" уже имеет другой нюанс - что, у человека с этим платьем что-то связано, или оно действительно эксклюзивное, очень дорогое, от знаменитого дизайнера - то есть, у человека с этим платьем как бы личные отношения, человек им гордится, это лучшшая часть его гардероба;
- а вот о  еде мы говорим "любить" даже если это имеет значение "нравится", и никаких эксклюзивных отношений с этой едой у нас нет: *"Я люблю молоко. Мой ребенок не любит рыбу."* А "нравится" о еде  - это, опять же,о конкретной порции, которую вы едите: *"Мне не нравится этот суп - слишком жирный. Киевские котлеты мне в этом ресторане не нравятся."*

Это, конечно, только наблюдения. Вывести из них четкую формулу употребления этих глаголов я пока не в стостоянии. Подскажите?

Answer (score 1):

Выразил бы, что понял, так: "я люблю" = "я испытываю положительное чувство к объекту вообще", а "мне нравится" = "я испытываю приятные ощущения от объекта". 
"Я люблю" и "мне нравится" могут не совпадать в каких-то ситуациях.
Мне может **не нравиться** состояние, в котором находится **любимая**, например.

Answer (score 0):

Боюсь, что почти все вами сказанное очень субъективно.
Я принципиальных различий в занчениях не вижу. ну помимо того, что любить - более сильное чувсто, но и это не всегда. Иногда "нравиться" просто шире чем "любить".  
"Мне нравится, как они готовят" (про ресторанную кухню, например). "Люблю" здесь как-то режет слух. "Мне нравится ход ваших мыслей".  И т.д.

Answer (score 0):

"Я люблю это платье" - на мой взгляд довольно субъективное мнение, то есть некая характеристика, относящаяся к внутреннему восприятию некого предмета или явления.  "Мне нравится это платье" - мнение более объективное, то есть скорее суждение, оценка предмета, так или иначе считающееся с тем, что существуют и другие мнения, другие оценки этого же предмета. 
  "Мне очень нравятся эти джинсы" ... потому что мне в них удобно, они мне совсем не жмут и в них так много карманов... 
  "Я очень люблю эти джинсы" ... так именно в них я был тем летом когда встретил её, в тот знойный июньский вечер ...

Answer (score 0):

Наверное, не «разъяснение» употребления слов и чёткая «формула» употребления этих глаголов вас интересует, а смысл понятий. Вопрос тогда не был бы ограничен двумя этими словами, так как есть и Уважаю, Млею, Впечатлил, В моём вкусе, Обожаю, Предпочитаю, Выбираю и пр. Вот только, если эти слова — любить, нравиться — рассматривать, то надо привести к одному знаменателю, представив их однотипно по части речи: **любовь/нрав**, или же **любовь/норов**.

По одну сторону здесь чувство, по другую — характер. И, поскольку, вполне можно представить их в одной речевой связке: **люблю нрав**, зеркальное же употребление — **нравится любовь**, кажется нелепой, но её вариант **нравится любить** возможен как каламбурный, то сопоставлять их противоестественно.

Чёткой же формулы не найти. При всей позитивности слов о симпатиях, их проявления зачастую агрессивны или парадоксальны: «Она любила попрекнуть зятя куском хлеба».

Comment: "Неравнодушен" пишется вместе.

Answer (score 0):

Нравиться = быть по нраву, подходить к складу характера или поведению.  Только возвратная форма осталась в употреблении, похоже.

Разница, по-моему, только в том, что при соответствующем глаголе противоположные существительные/местоимения играют роли подлежащего и дополнения.  *Я люблю эту песню* (я - подлежащее, песня - дополнение).  *Мне нравится эта песня* (я - дополнение, песня - подлежащее).

И, хотя Викисловарь отмечает, что "любить" выражает более интенсивное чувтство, мне не кажется это определяющим.

> Люблю грозу в начале мая...

Ну, какое там особой глубины чувство у поэта было к явлению природы?

> Розы любят воду.

Ещё бы!  Они без неё прожить не могут...

Единственное объяснение, которое приходит на ум, хотя и невозможно сказать, насколько определяющим оно является, - в том, что "любят" что-то обычно в изоляции этого чего-то, а "нравится" что-то зачастую в сравнении (прямом или подсознательном, недосказанном).

Answer (score 0):

У меня нет объективного ответа, но могу поделиться своей формулой:

Для меню эти действия различны не по ширине, а по глубине, на которую они направлены. "Люблю" - это про отношение к сути человека, сущности явления или значению предмета в моей жизни. А "нравится" - про внешнее впечатление, про реакцию на форму, обстоятельства или поступок.

Поэтому можно, например, присмотреться к тому, кто не нравится, и разглядеть в нём то, что любишь.